# Всегда ли то, что после тире или двоеточия (в рамках одного предложения) должно решать задачу именно этих знаков?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, двоеточие

Например, здесь иначе. То что решает задачу выделено жирным, а далее ещё текст. Можно ли так?

> Если Кирилл из-за заканчивающегося тестового периода **не может утихомириться – придут на помощь**, то у Павла напротив психическая организация соответствует характерному спокойствию.
>
> Это были **хорошие времена: финансовое благополучие и физическое здоровье не подводили**, (;) но покоя, разумеется, быть не могло никак.

Answer (score 2):

Keny Valisamin, Вас удивляет невнимание к этому вопросу, а меня вот нисколько. Если я вижу неряшливо оформленную фразу, я тоже прохожу мимо: какой толк искать синтаксические нормы, если с содержанием и речью беда?

*Если Кирилл из-за заканчивающегося тестового периода не может утихомириться – придут на помощь, то у Павла напротив психическая организация соответствует характерному спокойствию.*

Здесь проблема не в тире, тире как раз на месте: При препозиции придаточного  условного или времени вместо запятой часто ставят тире, там появляется оттенок следствия, но у Вас часть *"придут на помощь"* вторглась в сложное сопоставительное предложение с двойным  союзом если...то:

*Если Кирилл из-за заканчивающегося тестового периода не может утихомириться, то у Павла, напротив, психическая организация соответствует характерному спокойствию.*

Можно синтаксис поправить:
*Если Кирилл из-за заканчивающегося тестового периода не может утихомириться и ему требуется помощь, то у Павла, напротив, психическая организация соответствует характерному спокойствию.*

...психическая организация соответствует характерному спокойствию -  эта фраза вызывает вопросы. Психическая организация может соответствовать какому-то виду, типу, например, темперамента, а вот спокойствию, да ещё характерному... А для чего оно характерно? Много непонятного. Можно сказать:

*Если Кирилл из-за заканчивающегося тестового периода не может утихомириться и ему требуется помощь, то у Павла, напротив, психическое состояние стабильное, спокойное.*

*Это были хорошие времена: финансовое благополучие и физическое здоровье не подводили, (;) но покоя, разумеется, быть не могло никак.* - а здесь в чём вопрос?  Двоеточие стоит на месте. БСП, второе предложение раскрывает содержание первого, можно вставить "а именно": *...хорошие времена, а именно:финансовое благополучие и физическое здоровье не подводили,* И запятая, и точка с запятой будут на месте. Запятая перед противительным союзом  НО более уместна, точка с запятой может быть объяснима наличием осложнения в виде вводного слова, но я бы оставила запятую.