# Нужна ли запятая и почему? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобрать предложение:

> Может потому что слишком сильно, и на Нигерию лишь распространяется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Не вызывало панику и то, что войска Гамбии активизировались. Может, потому что слишком сильно и на Нигерию лишь распространялась*

СПП с двумя однородными придаточными причины, поэтому запятой перед **и** нет. Это парцеллированная конструкция. Главное предложение в первом. Вводное слово относится к обоим придаточным.

Должно быть: *Не вызывало панику и то, что войска Гамбии активизировались,(**возможно и тире**) **может**, **потому что** слишком сильно и (**потому что**) на Нигерию (агрессия) лишь распространялась*.

Можно поставить ещё запятую после "потому", ведь на него падает фразовое ударение (**почему** не вызывало панику?-**потому**, что...)

Comment: Людмила, не могли бы вы на [этот (ссылка)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443505/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE) вопрос ответить? Не понимаю почему его так вниманием обделили...

Answer (score 1):

**Предложение очень  неясное, чтобы говорить о постановке или отсутствии запятой.**
В любом случае запятая после "может" ставится, если оно вводное, и не ставится, если оно выступает в качестве члена предложения. 
МОЖЕТ, вводное слово

То же, что «может быть, возможно, вероятно». Подробно о пунктуации при вводных словах и сочетаниях.

В том селе был у одного козака, прозвищем Коржа, работник, которого люди звали Петром Безродным; может, оттого, что никто не помнил ни отца его, ни матери. Н. Гоголь, Вечер накануне Ивана Купала. Шаганэ ты моя, Шаганэ! // Там, на севере, девушка тоже, // На тебя она страшно похожа, // Может, думает обо мне... С. Есенин, Шаганэ ты моя, Шаганэ... Звон кружил, дрожал не умолкая, // А она стояла у окна, // Всей душою, может, понимая, // Что менять решенья не должна. Э. Асадов, Телефонный звонок.

! Не смешивать с употреблением в роли члена предложения (сказуемого).

Было душно от жгучего света, // А взгляды его – как лучи. // Я только вздрогнула: этот // Может меня приручить. А. Ахматова, Смятение.

Comment: А что на счёт запятой перед "и"?

Comment: –@KenyValisamin, повторюсь: предложение настолько непонятно, что говорить о запятой перед ***и*** тоже нет смысла.

Comment: Я дополню: _"**Не вызывало панику и то, что войска Гамбии активизировались.** Может потому что слишком сильно, и на Нигерию лишь распростран**ялась (активизация, агрессия)**"._ Здесь я не могу понять сколько грамматических основ у второго предложения...

Comment: По-моему, никакие знаки препинания это предложение не спасут. С любыми знаками оно останется ребусом.